# Verse numbering across stanzas in memoir class

Tags: memoir, verse

It seems that the last verses of stanzas in not numbered in the verse environment of the memoir class:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\linenumberfrequency{1}
\verselinenumbersleft

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
C'était fini. Splendide, étincelant, superbe, \\
Luisant sur la cité comme la faulx sur l'herbe, \\
Large acier dont le jour faisait une clarté, \\
Ayant je ne sais quoi dans sa tranquillité \\
De l'éblouissement du triangle mystique, \\
Pareil à la lueur au fond d'un temple antique, \\
Le fatal couperet relevé triomphait. \\
Il n'avait rien gardé de ce qu'il avait fait \\
Qu'une petite tache imperceptible et rouge.

Le bourreau s'en était retourné dans son bouge ; \\
Et la peine de mort, remmenant ses valets, \\
Juges, prêtres, était rentrée en son palais, \\
Avec son tombereau terrible dont la roue, \\
Silencieuse, laisse un sillon dans la boue \\
Qui se remplit de sang sitôt qu'elle a passé. \\
La foule disait : bien ! car l'homme est insensé, \\
Et ceux qui suivent tout, et dont c'est la manière, \\
Suivent même ce char et même cette ornière.

J'étais là. Je pensais. Le couchant empourprait \\
Le grave Hôtel de Ville aux luttes toujours prêt, \\
Entre Hier qu'il médite et Demain dont il rêve. \\
L'échafaud achevait, resté seul sur la Grève, \\
Sa journée, en voyant expirer le soleil. \\
Le crépuscule vint, aux fantômes pareil. \\
Et j'étais toujours là, je regardais la hache, \\
La nuit, la ville immense et la petite tache.
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF result]

Is there a way I can make the last verses of stanzas numbered? Or am I making stanzas the wrong way?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Victor Hugo?

Comment: Add a `\\ ` at the end of the last verse.

Comment: I tried it, but the gap between stanzas disappears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should use `\\!` for the final verse in a stanza when lines are numbered, but with `babel-french` active this cannot work, because `!` is a special character in French.

We need to fix `\\` in verse in order it can properly scan for `!` after it.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\linenumberfrequency{1}
\verselinenumbersleft

%% fix for French
\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`~=`! \lowercase{\endgroup
  \renewcommand{\@vsifbang}[1]{\@ifnextchar ~{\@firstoftwo{#1}}}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
C'était fini. Splendide, étincelant, superbe, \\
Luisant sur la cité comme la faulx sur l'herbe, \\
Large acier dont le jour faisait une clarté, \\
Ayant je ne sais quoi dans sa tranquillité \\
De l'éblouissement du triangle mystique, \\
Pareil à la lueur au fond d'un temple antique, \\
Le fatal couperet relevé triomphait. \\
Il n'avait rien gardé de ce qu'il avait fait \\
Qu'une petite tache imperceptible et rouge.\\!

Le bourreau s'en était retourné dans son bouge ; \\
Et la peine de mort, remmenant ses valets, \\
Juges, prêtres, était rentrée en son palais, \\
Avec son tombereau terrible dont la roue, \\
Silencieuse, laisse un sillon dans la boue \\
Qui se remplit de sang sitôt qu'elle a passé. \\
La foule disait : bien ! car l'homme est insensé, \\
Et ceux qui suivent tout, et dont c'est la manière, \\
Suivent même ce char et même cette ornière.\\!

J'étais là. Je pensais. Le couchant empourprait \\
Le grave Hôtel de Ville aux luttes toujours prêt, \\
Entre Hier qu'il médite et Demain dont il rêve. \\
L'échafaud achevait, resté seul sur la Grève, \\
Sa journée, en voyant expirer le soleil. \\
Le crépuscule vint, aux fantômes pareil. \\
Et j'étais toujours là, je regardais la hache, \\
La nuit, la ville immense et la petite tache.\\!
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

No fix is generally necessary if the languages loaded with `babel` don't make `!` into a shorthand.

[image]